# Generic type any to concrete type cannot be performed

Tags: swift

I'm trying to practice generics so I probably missed something obvious and could use some help.

```
enum CacheTime {
    case short
    case long
}


struct Cached<T: Equatable> {
    
    let object: T
    let type: CacheTime
    
    init(_ object: T, type: CacheTime) {
        self.object = object
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

I then want to use this type with an actual concrete type as a property. I thought I could do:

```
struct Holder {

  var people: Cached<[Person]> = []

}
```

I get the error that cannot convert value of type `[Any]` to specified type `Cached<[Person]>`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `people` as an array which is not. It is expecting a Cached object something like this

```
Cached([Person](), type: .short))
```

Answer (score 1):

To shorten your code, you can use `propertyWrapper`s. Your `Cached` struct would be:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Cached<T: Equatable> {
    var wrappedValue: T
    let type: CacheTime
    
    init(wrappedValue: T, type: CacheTime) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
struct Holder {
    @Cached<[Person]>(type: .short) var people = []
}
```